# angularjs ui tinymce integration issue

Tags: javascript, debugging, angularjs

I am having problem in integrating [AngularJS UI tinymce](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-tinymce) in the app, however it is working fine in jsbin demo:

http://jsbin.com/itevos/2

However in app I receive this error when I load the app:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of null
```

which references tiny_mce_jquery_src.js:11955 with that line number being:

```
var n = t.getElement().form;
```

In the app, I checked all js/css files are loaded fine. This is what I have:

```
var app_htmleditor_module = angular.module('app_htmleditor', ['ui', 'components']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: getBaseURL() + 'public/tpl/app/htmleditor.htm',
                controller: HtmlEditorCtrl,
                reloadOnSearch:false
            }).
            otherwise( {redirectTo: '/'});
    }
]);
```

And textarea:

```
<textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="tinymce" id="{{fileUploaderID}}_html_tab" name="{{fileUploaderID}}_html_tab"></textarea>
```

I tried wrapping textarea with `form` tag but still received the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dev555 There were issues with this directive but I know that we've updated recently. Please let us know if there are still problems. As an aside, angular-ui is in its early stages things change quite rapidly.

Comment: Yes I updated and used latest tinymce.js directive and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code and works fine, the only difference in mine is that I have only dependency with ui

```
angular.module('amiguiAdmin', ['amiguiAdmin.directives', 'ui'])
```

and also there is no form tag in the  page.

I hope this will help you.

Regards